# How can I model this route in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to model routes that act a little strange to me. Here is what they would like me to do:

```
/AssetManagement -> Asset Landing page
/AssetManagement/Add -> Add an asset
/AssetManagement/Edit -> Edit an asset
/AssetManagement/Locations -> Locations landing page
/AssetManagement/Locations/Add -> Add a location
/AssetManagement/Locations/Edit -> Edit a location
```

I'm not sure, but I think this needs to be modeled with two controllers. AssetsController and LocationsController. I think the views Add/Edit/Index would exist under the respected View folders and I would probably have two routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AssetManagement", // Route name
    "AssetManagement/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Assets", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new[] { "MyApplication.Web.Website.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "AssetManagementLocations", // Route name
    "AssetManagement/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Locations", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new[] { "MyApplication.Web.Website.Controllers" }
);
```

It just feels a bit wrong to me. Am I missing a best practice on handling stuff? What kinds of problems could this cause down the road? A lot of the system they want me to build works like this.

// Edit
If this is a bad place to ask questions like this, where should I ask them?

Comment: Consider thinking about why "It just feels a bit wrong to me" and see if more info needs to be added to the question... Since you can setup routes whatever way you feel good (like all on one controller, all separate, with areas....) it is hard to suggest better route without understanding why this one is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a Area.

In the area create 2 controllers one for asset and other for Location.

Instead of playing with routes(which can be dangerous) play with the MVC concept.

The 2nd Route you have specified closely relates to Areas.
When you create the area the route is automatically created for you.
hope this helps.

```
Area - AssetManagement
   Controller1 - HomeController 
              Action1 - Add
              Action2 - Delete 

   Controller2 - LocationsController
              Action1 - Add
              Action2 - Delete 

routes.MapRoute(
    "AssetManagementLocations", // Route name
    "{Area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Locations", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new[] { "MyApplication.Web.Website.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the attributerouting project. You can Nuget install into mvc and decorate your action methods or controllers with the path- this leads to clear intention of exactly which routes map to which controller/method

https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/2.-Usage